# Cmd script does not work properly

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, script, cmd.exe

I created a script that adds Compatibility Mode via `cmd`, but I'm having problems getting it to work:

```bat
Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%CD%\mha2.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "WINXPSP3 256COLOR 640X480" /f

:: # For testing only:
   MkDir Success
   Exit
```

- When executing the script via the GUI, directory `Success` gets created, but Compatibility Mode is not set; it does not matter if I run the script with/without Admin privileges
- When executing the script with Admin privileges via the following, it does everything it should:

  ```bat
  Start "C:\Path\To\script.bat"
  ```

Why is this the case and how do I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I actually know that. It was a misspelling. Corrected it.

Comment: And I've fixed the bit you missed, like the title and the content of the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of work, I figured it out: Admin privileges are required to start the script when including a one-liner before `Reg Add`, as `cmd` will start it in `%WinDir%\system32`.

- In case somebody wants to do the same thng:

  ```bat
  @echo off

  :: # BatchGotAdmin
  :-------------------------------------
  REM # --> Check for permissions
    if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
      >nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\config\system"
    ) else (
      >nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\system32\config\system"
    )

  REM # --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
    if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
      Echo "Requesting administrative privileges..."
      GoTo UACPrompt
    ) else ( GoTo GotAdmin )

  :UACPrompt
    Echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    Set params= %*
    Echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params:"=""%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    Del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    Exit /b

  :GotAdmin
    Pushd "%CD%"
    Cd /d "%~dp0"
  :--------------------------------------

  Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%CD%\mha2.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN98 256COLOR 640X480" /f
  ```

Comment: When modifying case-sensitivity for correct syntax highlighting, I noticed a few potential issues within the script: `cacls` is no longer used (since at least Win 8), instead use `icacls` in lieu of; and the `UAC.ShellExecute` command appears to be missing a closing quote after `"/c` _(I initially added a closing `"`, but removed it after @it-wasnt-me confirmed it worked without it)_. While trivial and only as an FYI, it's more efficient to use `%WinDir%` in lieu of `%SystemRoot%`.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

2>nul "%__APPDIR__%whoami.exe" /groups | find "S-1-16-12288" >nul && goto=:gotAdmin 

echo\Requesting administrative privileges... && set "_args=%*" && set "_flag=1" && >"%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ^
echo=CreateObject("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "%~sdpnx0", "!_args:"=""!", "RunAsAdministrator", "runas", 1 :WScript.Quit 

%__AppDir__%cscript.exe "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"|find/v "." & echo\<nul & cd. & 2>nul del /q /f "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && goto=:EOF 

:gotAdmin
cd /d "%~dp0" && set "_Reg_Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
%__AppDir__%reg.exe add "!_Reg_Key!" /v \""!CD!\Launcher.exe\"" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN98 256COLOR 640X480" /f
 
2>&1 %__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "!_Reg_Key!"|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /i Launcher.exe.*WIN98.256COLOR.640X480 && ^
echo\Requesting admin works || echo\Not works, sorry... & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 && endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

---

How about another command to simplify the verification of administrator privilege:

```bat
ExecuteCMD && return 0 and I'm the admin and goto label :gotAdmin
The last command was unsuccessful because I'm not the admin and now I'll create and call vbs file... 


Whoami.exe | find "S-1-16-12288" && goto=:gotAdmin 
The last command was unsuccessful because I'm not the admin and now I'll create and call vbs file...
```

Comment: Script is missing a closing `"` for `"!_args:"=""!"`, which is why the syntax highlighting is all out of whack.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, but this came from autor code  (`set param= %*  and  %params:"=""%`)

Comment: Did you test your script? I'm not on a PC at the moment, but at first glance, it looks like it would error out due to an open double quote

Comment: @JW0914 yEp, full tested!! Again, thanks for comment!